# How to display json format in rails retrieving data from postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, heroku, format

I'm new and I'm learning the basics but suddenly I have to display all the data from *postgresql*, using *rails*, in ***json*** format that is deployed to **heroku**.

My goal is to connect **vb.net** to **rails** before connecting to the database.
Please help me. I am new in this field.

As of now, I tried to run my codes in localhost trying to display data from sqlite to ***localhost:3000/employees*** in json format.

I have this code in my **Employee Controller**

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

 respond_to :json
 def index
   @employees = Employee.all
   respond_with(@employees) do |format|
   format.json { render :json => @employees.to_json(:only => [:fname, :mname, :lname]) }
  end
 end

 def show
   @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
   @employee = Employee.new
 end

 def create
   @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

   @employee.save
   redirect_to @employee
 end

 private
 def employee_params
   params.require(:employee).permit(:fname, :mname, :lname)
 end
end
```

and this is my code in **app/views/employees/index**

```
  <% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= employee.fname %></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td><%= employee.mname %></td>
    <td></td><td></td>
    <td><%= employee.lname %></td>
  </tr>
```

and this is in my **gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  #gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

when i run the program, i receive this error message
***ActionController::UnknownFormat in EmployeesController#index***

*Extracted source (around line #9):*

```
def index
  @employees = Employee.all
  respond_with(@employees) do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @employees.to_json(:only => [:fname, :mname, :lname]) }
  end
end
```

specifically this part:  `respond_with(@employees) do |format|`
*app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:9:in `index'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used this and it went just fine

```
 def index
    render json: @employees = Employee.all
 end
```

providing that `gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'` is in the gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to generate `JSON`. It's easy to use and highly reusable. I think it's good to start with good tools. It will make your code cleaner and easier to maintain.

You could have something like that:

```
#EmployeesController
def index
   @employees = Employee.all
   respond_with(@employees) do |format|
   format.json { render template: "api/employees/index"}
  end
end

#app/views/api/employees/index.json.rabl
object @employees
extends 'api/employees/show'

#app/views/api/employees/show.json.rabl
object @employee
attributes :fname, :mname, :lname
```